# Wayland compositor seems to behave differently with my GLFW code, mainly missing window decorators

Tags: linux, xorg, gnome, opengl, wayland

To start off, this is a completely fresh install of Arch Linux + Gnome with Wayland. Downloaded the respective packages of `glfw-wayland`, `glew-wayland` in order to build my program, and ran it.

I noticed that window decorators are missing, the minimize, maximize, and close buttons. In fact, the window title bar is missing as well, what is there is just a blank small bar with nothing on it. I'm not sure if this is a GLFW issue or a Linux/Gnome specific issue, because prior to this I used KDE on X11 and it would work fine.

I tried to set window decorators via `glfwSetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_TRUE);` but that did not do anything.

A screenshot of what I see on Wayland:

[image: img1]

An older screenshot of my code on X11:

[image: img2]

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Tried googling but I could not find any information besides the attribute from earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, its a gnome specific issue. GNOME doesn't support XDG decoration.

There's a PR that's attempting to fix it but this is just the way it is for gnome.

https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/2212